# Problem when using alien to install Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: debian, software-installation, dpkg, alien

I am trying to use `alien --scripts` to make a `.noarch.rpm` file into a `.deb` file, however, it is not working. I am trying to install Oracle SQL Developer:

I have downloaded the `sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm` package from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html).

```
alien --scripts sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm
```

at this point I would expect the file the file `sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84-2_all.deb` to be created so I could call the following command to install it:

```
dpkg -i sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84-2_all.deb
```

However this is not the case. When I call `alien --scripts sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm` I get a folder with the name `sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84`. After looking in the folder, I have found that there is a large proportion of the program missing, the folder which contains all of the executable scripts to set up and run SQL Developer.

I am using a `Debian Linux sever, release 6.0.10.

Is there a way for me to make it create the `.deb` file when I call the `alien --scripts` command?

Comment: Does the conversion output any messages?

Comment: @FaheemMitha When I call the `alien --scripts` command it doesn't output anything, it just creates the folder with some of the files it, however, the command doesn't finish executing (as in it doesn't go back to `root@...:/home/...` until you press `^C`. I'm not sure why that is, I have tried leaving it to run for 30 minutes+ before now, and get the same result.

Comment: You should let it finish, converting sqldeveloper takes a very long time...

Comment: Try first without the `--scripts` option.

Comment: @FaheemMitha That run but returns the following:

`Warning: Skipping conversion of scripts in package sqldeveloper: postinst
Warning: Use the --scripts parameter to include the scripts.`

Comment: @James How do the results of these two different options differ? Do neither of them include the scripts?

Comment: @FaheemMitha As far as I can tell they are missing an entire directory, which, yes, contains almost all of the scripts for the package, as well as configuration files for the program.

Comment: Do they produce exactly the same results? If not, what are the differences?

Comment: @FaheemMitha The results are identical.

Comment: @James Ok, you said you interrupted the `--scripts` version. I suggest letting it run for a while. You can check whether it is performing any I/O activity by doing `iotop`. And `top` will show if it is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
alien -r --scripts sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: Why? What do you expect this to do that the original doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to install SQLDeveloper on a fresh Ubuntu 23.04 install.

Since the asker says "I am trying to **install** Oracle SQL Developer", the `--install` flag is useful. From the help:

> `-i`, `--install`: Automatically install each generated package, and remove the package file after it has been installed.

```shell
sudo apt install alien openjdk-11-jdk
```

Download `.rpm` in current folder (here, using `sqldeveloper-23.1.0.097.1607.noarch.rpm`); then:

```shell
sudo alien -i sqldeveloper-*.rpm   # Wait several minutes
sqldeveloper
```

`alien` gives me the following warnings, but still works:

```
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
Warning: Skipping conversion of scripts in package sqldeveloper: postinst
Warning: Use the --scripts parameter to include the scripts.
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-23.1.0-097.1607.noarch
        dpkg --no-force-overwrite -i sqldeveloper_23.1.0-98.1607_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package sqldeveloper.
(Reading database ... 220460 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack sqldeveloper_23.1.0-98.1607_all.deb ...
Unpacking sqldeveloper (23.1.0-98.1607) ...
Setting up sqldeveloper (23.1.0-98.1607) ...
```